# A new entity was found through the relationship *** that was not configured to cascade persist operations

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, silex

I am trying to make a simple two-step form:

1. Step One: Select target **Product**
2. Step Two: See **Product Price**, put **Order Title** and place order.

Using Symfony Form Component in Silex, I am getting this error:

> A new entity was found through the relationship '**Order**#**product**' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: '**Product**'

---

## Entities:

**1 - Product**

```
Class Product {

    OneToMany(targetEntity="Order", mappedBy="product", cascade={"persist","remove"})
    private $orders;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->orders = new ArrayCollection()
    }
}
```

**2 - Order**

```
Class Order {

    ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="orders")
    private $product;
}
```

---

## Form Types:

**1 - OrderProductType** (Choose target product)

```
Class OrderProductType extends AbstractType
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Order::class,
        ));
    }

    public function buildForm($builder) {
        $builder
            ->add('product', EntityType::class, array(
                'class'              => Product::class,
            )->getForm();

        return $form;
    }
}
```

**2 - OrderType**

```
Class OrderType extends AbstractType
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Order::class,
        ));
    }

    public function buildForm($builder) {
        $builder
            ->add('product_price', TextType::class, array(
                'data'               => $order->getProduct()->getPrice(),
                'mapped'             => false,
                'disabled'           => true,
            ))
            ->add('title', TextType::class)->getForm();

        return $form;
    }
}
```

---

## Controllers:

**1 - Set Product**

```
public function setProduct(Application $app, Request $request)
{
    $order = new Order();

    $form = $app['form.factory']->create(OrderProductType::class, $order);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $order = $form->getData();
        $app['session']->set('dummyOrder', $order);

        return $app->redirect($app['url_generator']->generate('orders_add'));

    }

    return $app['twig']->render('orders/add.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

**2 - Add Order**

```
public function add(Application $app, Request $request)
{
    $order = $app['session']->get('dummyOrder');

    $form = $app['form.factory']->create(OrderType::class, $order);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $order = $form->getData();

        $app['em']->persist($order);
        $app['em']->flush();

        $app['session']->remove('dummyOrder');

        return $app->redirect($app['url_generator']->generate('orders_show', ['id' => $order->getId()]));

    }

    return $app['twig']->render('orders/add.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

---

## Attempts:

What I tried so far:

1. Tried to replace the `redirect` with a `sub-request forward`, passing json-encoded `product` entity, with no success.
2. Tried to switch the **Product**-**Order** relationship from BiDirectional to UniDirectional with no success.
3. Tried to merge the `product` with no success.
4. Tried to persist `order` in first form step and merge it at second with no success.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the serialisation of the order object.

When you serialise `$order` by `$app['session']->set('dummyOrder', $order);` and then deserialise it at `$order = $app['session']->get('dummyOrder');` the `Product` object is no longer managed by Doctrine.

That's why when you try to save `$order` at `add()` you get an error.

For your case I'd suggest two solutions.

1. Save the order to the DB (with some flag like 'temporary') and pass the order ID to the session. Then retrieve the order from the DB with Doctirne.

Replace session setting in `setProduct()` with

```
$app['session']->set('dummyOrderProductId', $order->getProduct()->getId());
```

Then replace retrieving of order in `add()` (pseudocode)

```
$order = new Order();
$product = $em->getRepository(Product::class)->findOneById($app['session']->get('dummyOrderProductId'))
$order->setProduct($product);
```

2. Read product ID from the `$order` at `setProduct()` and pass it to the session. Then again create new `$order` in `add()`, read product from the DB and add it to the `$order`.

In both cases you will keep `Product` managed by Doctrine and avoid the issue you have.

Comment: Used debugger and the `$order` has associated `$product` in `add()`. So I think you are wrong

Comment: Yes you have a product loaded from the session but the product is not managed by the entity manager because of the redirect.  So the entity manager thinks the product is brand new.  Storing entities in the session is just asking for trouble.  Not sure of the cleanest way to fix it.  I think I would add productId to the order_add url and then load product from the database in your order add method.

Comment: @Cerad I managed to fixed this part by persisting the `$product` instead of `$order`. but problem replicated, as I have this sequence of correlated entities: User->Account->Request->Product->Order. Now the problem is on Request-Product relationship. Should I start with the `User` entity to persist an order?

Comment: @Trix - I think the basic issue is using the session to store entities between requests.  Even if you get this part working you will just run into other problems.  Get rid of the session stuff or if you really really really feel you need sessions then only store ids.

Comment: I've added a concrete example to my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please provide full code. This is not valid PHP code:

```
OneToMany(targetEntity="Order", mappedBy="product", cascade={"persist","remove"})
private $orders;
```

And information about columns is missing.

But talking about the problem, it seems you have a wrong Doctrine mapping. You should have `cascade` option where you have a mapping, in this case - in `Order` entity. On product side it's not really a mapping, it's only a reference to a mapping (`mappedBy="product"`)

```
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="orders", cascade={"persist","remove"})
```

Comment: Is `* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="orders", cascade={"persist","remove"})` a valid PHP code? By the way What do you mean by `You should have cascade option where you have a mapping`? What do you call a **mapping**?